# Can't get Laravel-Filemanager to work in subfolder on remote server

Tags: laravel, ckeditor, filepath

In my Laravel 5.7 site I use Ckeditor together with Laravel-Filemanager. After following all the installation instructions I got it to work fine locally. No problems att all. But I cannot get it to work in my remote web server.

On the remote server I have placed the Laravel app in a subfolder 2 levels down from the webroot.

In my blade template I have this (I have tried using both asset and url helpers in the option urls and both of them works locally):

```
<script src="{{ asset('vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/ckeditor.js') }}"></script>
<script>
    var options = {
    filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: "{{ url('/laravel-filemanager?type=Images') }}",
    filebrowserImageUploadUrl: "{{ url('/laravel-filemanager/upload?type=Images&_token=') }}"
};
</script>
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', options);
</script>
```

When I want to upload an image in my CKeditor by clicking the `Browse server` button in my local environment it works as it should and the URL looks like this in Laravel File Manager ('laravel/' being the webroot):

```
http://laravel/laravel-filemanager?type=Images&CKEditor=editor1&CKEditorFuncNum=0&langCode=sv
```

When I do the same thing in my remote server the URL looks like this:

```
http://www.myremoteserver.com/subfolder1/subfolder2/public/laravel-filemanager?type=Images&CKEditor=editor1&CKEditorFuncNum=0&langCode=sv
```

... **and all I get is a 404.**

I have tried to clear route, config and site caches. I have also tried to copy the URL above in the remote environment and pasting it a new window without the /public/ part.

Is there anyone out there that can guess what is going on? All help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have used Laravel File Manager and tinyMCE. When I had it like on production, some routes from LFM broke. On local dev, it was working fine. After some debugging, it turned out my Nginx route configs were wrong. Try having a look at your Webserver and Reverse proxy.

Comment: Thanks Adis, I will look into that.

Answer (score 0):

please share with me how got the ckeditor to upload files when you click send to server because i have being searching for it for about 2 days now yet no solution.
iam using `laravel 5.7`
and unisharp laravel-filemanager but no solution was found.
I only saw to add `config.filebrowserUploadMethod = 'form';`
in the `ckeditor congi.js` but even after adding that i still didn't get any solution.
every other things seems to be working fine.
please i will be glad to receive your assistance

Comment: Hello, excuse me for this late answer. I will post an answer to my own question below.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work. I wiped the web server folder clean and uploaded all files again from the beginning manually instead of doing it by cloning the GIT repo. And then it worked. So I actually am not sure what was wrong.

Anyhow I added this snippet below where I wanted the CKeditor in my blade template:

```
<textarea id="editor1" name="story" class="form-control">{{ $story }}</textarea>
```

And this near the bottom of the blade template, just before `@endsection`.

```
  <script src="{{ asset('vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/ckeditor.js') }}"></script>
    <script>
        var options = {
            filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: "{{ url('/laravel-filemanager?type=Images') }}",
            filebrowserImageUploadUrl: "{{ url('/laravel-filemanager/upload?type=Images&_token=') }}"
        };
    </script>
    <script>
        CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', options);
    </script>
```

Be sure to publish as per the filemanager instructions:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=lfm_config
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=lfm_public
```

And clear caches:

```
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

Also check that the `vendor` folder exists in your public directory with CKeditor and Laravel filemanager folders inside it, otherwise the `asset` and `url` helpers will not work. Also check in the dev window (F12 in browser) what your current path is to ckeditor.js.